# Update the Gridview for each iteration of a foreach loop c#.net

Tags: c#, gridview, foreach

I want to know how to update the GridView after each iteration of a for-each loop in c#.net web application. I have used for-each loop to travel through each row in the GridView. I want to change `BackColor` of current row real-time.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    // code to make changes per row
    row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Why the 100ms delay after each iteration? The reason it's not showing the color change until after the loop is because the method call, including the `Thread.Sleep()`, blocks the UI thread and prevents it from updating control changes.

Comment: This 1000ms delay is to check whether it is updated one by one. It doesn't work as I expected even without Thread.sleep(). All the color cells are displayed after the end of the for loop.

Comment: Each row IS updated one by one. The reason you don't see it is because your code is running on the UI thread. Your UI has to stop processing messages in order to run your `foreach`. This means that while your `foreach` is running, your program can literally do nothing else. Once the `foreach` ends, the UI begins updating again. It sees all the messages the loop produced that basically say `Change these row backcolors` and processes them all at once. This is why it appears that they're all changing at once.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I want to see it in the UI after each iteration. Is there any other way to do this? please help

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net project? Unfortunately my expertise with web projects is limited. In Winforms/WPF, you could do this with an asynchronous method that changed the color then used `await` on `Task.Delay()`. I don't know if web projects behave the same way with regards to UI updates.

Comment: Yes this is ASP.Net web project.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, a for loop is easier. However, as long as you're not deleting rows, this will suffice;

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[i];
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green // my favourite color
}
```

Comment: My question is how to display gridview changes in each iteration. Now, all the changes are displayed after the end of the for loop. I have tried using both for and foreach loop.

Comment: What do you mean by display changes? You wish to change the back color of the row in each iteration? Correct?

Comment: Yes, I wish to change the back color of the row in each iteration and display it in the interface real time. Now, changes are displayed after the for loop. I want to display changes during for loop and not after the end of the loop. please help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have amended the changes in my answer.

Comment: `In this situation, you cannot use a foreach loop.` This is not correct. A `foreach` loop will work just fine here. Changes to the `row` object in  `foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)` are made to the actual row in the `GridView`. The problem is the OP wants to make the updates without blocking the UI thread.